# ¿How to get ajax data?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I need to get the records of a specific row, im rendering the data with this code:

```
 $(function() 
 {
    $('#id_project').on('change', function() 
    {
        var id_project = $('#id_project').val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "ff.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:{id_project},
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data)
            {
                var datos = data.datas;
                alert(datos);
            },
        })
    });
 });
```

Comment: you have to log the data parameter of the success function

Comment: What is `cb`? you're not even trying to access what the server is responding with.

Comment: did you mean function(cb,nb_informacion_general_localizacion) ?, if is that, the error is the same.

Comment: cb is the callback

Comment: The data you are sending to the server needs to be formatted. For example: `data:'id_project=' + id_project` so that it can be obtained using `$_POST`

Comment: " 
cb is the callback ". What callback? Just based on the code above (which, don't forget, is all we have), `cb` will be undefined and give you a console error. If you want to look at the response from the server you have to look inside `data`. But since it looks like you echo your data raw without any kind of formatting or encoding, then your response is likely just a big indecipherable string of text (check the response in your browser's network tab to see it). Better to encode it as json maybe. Hundreds of examples of this online if you care to look.

Comment: the solution is?

Comment: If you want to look at the response from the server you have to look inside `data`, like I said. And encode your data from the server in some machine-readable format e.g. JSON or XML. What you want to use is up to you.

Comment: i make new data but im gettng the same error, any solution?

Comment: show what your JSON looks like. Probably it doesn't match the structure you're trying to use. You can check in your browser's network tab to see the ajax request and click on it, then view the response. In there you can see the JSON. If you still don't understand how to access the right part after you've seen it, then post the JSON here for us to look at.

Comment: Hello @ADyson heres the json [{"id_project":"4","nb_informacion_general_localizacion":"cuatro"}]  As you can see the json is valid

Comment: It's valid, but that doesn't mean the way you're accessing the contents is correct. See my answer.

Comment: of course, the way im making the json is at the top in my first post. take a look please

Comment: I posted the answer. The way you're creating the JSON is fine, because since you have a loop, there could in theory be multiple objects returned. It's the way you're accessing it in the JS that's problematic.

Comment: i found the solution, i deleted the array_data[] and work just perfect, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for the problem was the

```
$array_data[] = array('id_project' => $id_project,'nb_informacion_general_localizacion' => $nb_informacion_general_localizacion);
```

Just deleted that and after that, i call the data like this and works perfect, thanks to you all.

```
id = data.id_project
console.log(id);
```

Comment: In your question you were looking for the nb_informacion_general_localizacion variable, not the id_project. You didn't mention you wanted a different field. Also this can't be the whole solution, since if you delete that line, there will be nothing at all in your array_data to be serialised. Did you also change it so it json_encodes something else?

Comment: its the same dude, i test nb too, no problem with that

Answer (score 1):

Change DataType to json. A html response is expected while PHP returns json

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON contains one object wrapped in an array.

Therefore, `json_data.nb_informacion_general_localizacion` doesn't work because you're trying to directly access the property of the object, as if "json_data" was the object.

But "json_data" is an array, and arrays don't have properties, they have indexes. Your object is stored in the first index of the array. To get it you have to reference the index of the array you want, and *then* you can access the properties of the object which is stored at that index.

So very simply:

```
json_data[0].nb_informacion_general_localizacion
```

will get you what you need. The `[0]` denotes the first index of the array (since arrays in JavaScript are zero-based).

You also need to do what is mentioned in another answer and change `dataType: "html"` to `dataType: "json"`, otherwise jQuery will not treat your response as JSON, and won't turn it into a JS array.

Comment: i did that too, but nothings happens, ill post the correct way

Comment: "nothings happens". So...no console errors? Nothing logged in console? Sounds unlikely. Are you sure the ajax call even ran this time?

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/pymrok2L/1/ - a simplified example showing that, for the given data structure, my code works. If it doesn't work for you, then you've changed something else which you haven't shown in the question.